# ng-repeat causes form elements to not display

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to dynamically add a form input in AngularJS every time the add button is clicked. However, with the code I have, it the input elements don't display at all. I simply see the "Post" button. If I remove the `ng-repeat="ingredient in ingredients"`, the form displays (as expected). What am I doing wrong here?

Here is the specific code in index.ejs:

```
<form ng-model="recipe">
  <div class="form-inline" ng-repeat="ingredient in ingredients">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" ng-model="ingredient.name"></input>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Quantity" ng-model="ingredient.quantity"></input>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Unit" ng-model="ingredient.unit"></input>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <button type="button" id="add" ng-click="add()">Add</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Post</button>
</form>
```

Here is the corresponding js code:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', [
'$scope',
'posts',
'auth',
function($scope, posts, auth){
  $scope.ingredients = [];
  $scope.add = function() {
    var newItemNo = $scope.ingredients.length+1;
    $scope.ingredients.push({'id':'choice'+newItemNo});
  };
}]);
```

Comment: Works great here. I just moved the add button outside the `ng-repeat`. You have empty array to start ...so nothing to repeat over and `add()` is inside repeater http://plnkr.co/edit/x0cdBJ3aJTA5qK32wM3J?p=preview

Comment: In other words..nothing to repeat means nothing will show. Can hide the post button with `ng-show="ingredients.length"`

Answer (score 0):

That's because your button is in the `ng-repeat`ed element. `ng-repeat` repeats the HTML *inside the element* it is assigned to. Since you have no items in `ingredients`, nothing is rendered - including your button

Just move your button out of `<div class="form-inline">`.

Answer (score 0):

Your add button is inside the ng-repeat, so it's never shown, so you can never populate the array, so it can't ever show.  Does that make sense?

Try

```
<form ng-model="recipe">
  <div class="form-inline" ng-repeat="ingredient in ingredients">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" ng-model="ingredient.name"></input>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Quantity" ng-model="ingredient.quantity"></input>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Unit" ng-model="ingredient.unit"></input>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <button type="button" id="add" ng-click="add()">Add</button>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Post</button>
</form>
```